# Using subtree push from branch to master

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to setup a multi branch system in my git repo. I have a 'dev' branch and a 'master' branch. What I'm hoping to do, is push my app's dist folder (typical yeoman app/ dist/ setup) to my master, which I can then pull down on my dedicated server.

I've performed this action once, and it worked, but now I just get the following error when running this command from dev:

Command

```
git subtree push --prefix dist origin master
```

Error:

```
To git@github.com:invisibled/invisible-sound.git
! [rejected]        4b8446f14f7db50578699fd1ccc88a04326ed6e1 -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:invisibled/invisible-sound.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I have been searching Google and SO for answers but none of them have helped me understand and get past this issue in my workflow. If anybody could provide any info or tips that would be great! Let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry if this is something you already considered but since there wasn't any answer yet I thought I'd take a shot.*

Typically that message means the repository you are pushing to changed since the last time you pushed to it. Because of that git doesn't know how to merge the two. Does it keep the changes at the remote or do you intend to overwrite them?

If that's the case just do a git pull from the remote and resolve any merge conflicts locally and then push the results back to the remote.

Answer (score 0):

I also used the subtree method for a while to push the typical Yeoman dist folder to a remote (in my case gh-pages). It's a make do but causes headaches when somehting gets changed on the server. You then have to resort to much less elegant solutions that create more hassle.

Now I switched to a much better solution: [grunt-build-control](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/grunt-build-control) by Rob Wierzbowski. Takes 10 mins to install but works like a charm and the whole deploying of the build folder to remotes becomes automatic. Completely version controlled and painless.

I see that its now also mentioned in the [Yeoman wiki](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Deployment).

Comment: oddly enough, we settled on that grunt plugin too! A much more elegant solution, we ditched that whole subtree thing after a few projects and it was never really smooth. Good to see Build Control mentioned with Yeoman, will save a lot of hassle for people.

Comment: True. Funny thing is I've been painstakingly doing the subtree hustle for months, but now I notice that grunt-build-control has been in that Wiki for a long time. I was working from the info on http://stephenplusplus.github.io/yeoman.io/deployment.html. It seems that the documentation is a little out of sync.